# Place switch icon on two textboxes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build the below layout in flutter. But need help to place the switch icon on top of two Containers . Currently these Containers are in colunm

[image]

```
class BodyContent extends StatelessWidget
{
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
  color: Colors.blue,    
   height: 350.0,    
   width: 400.0,  
   alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: Column(
  children: <Widget>[ 
    FromRow(),
    ChangeRow(),
    ToRow(),
  ]
  )
);
}    
}

class FromRow extends StatelessWidget
{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 0.0),
        height: 40.0, 
        width: 350.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))
      ),
        child:  new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(" From"),
          new Text("Hi whatsup?"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );    
  }  
 }

class ToRow extends StatelessWidget
{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        print("Container clicked");
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0),
        height: 40.0, 
        width: 350.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0))
      ),
        child:  new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(" To"),
          new Text("Hi whatsup?"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );   }  }

class ChangeRow extends StatelessWidget
{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
AssetImage logoAsset = AssetImage('images/banner.jpg');
Image image = Image(image:logoAsset,width: 100.0, height:100.0,);
return Container(child:image);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this putting your `Column Widget` inside a [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), and to align the `ChangeRow Widget` use a [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) as follows:

```
class BodyContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 350.0,
      width: 400.0,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            FromRow(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            ToRow(),
          ]),
          Positioned(
            top: 65.0,
            right: 40.0,
            child: ChangeRow(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```